# How to serialize primitive types in Rust?

Tags: rust

What's the proper way to use `serde` in order to serialize primitive types?
For example the following code snippet throws an error:

```
extern crate serde; // 1.0.137
use serde::Serialize;

fn main ()
{
    let test = true;
    let serialized: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    test.serialize(&mut serialized).unwrap();
    
}
```

And the error is:

> error[E0277]: the trait bound `&mut Vec<u8>: Serializer` is not satisfied

How can I serialize any primitive type into a byte vector/slice in Rust using `serde`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serde provides two things for serialization: the `Serialize` trait and the `Serializer` trait. The `Serialize` trait is used to describe any value that can be serialized, like your `test` boolean, while the `Serializer` trait is used to define the data format used for serialization. This is why a call to `serialize` needs a `Serializer`: serde has no built in data formats.

One thing you could consider using is [bincode](https://docs.rs/bincode/latest/bincode/index.html), which has a convenient `serialize` function that constructs the bincode `Serializer` and creates a vec:

```rust
let serialized: Vec<u8> = bincode::serialize(test).unwrap();
```

Serde's docs [have a list of more data formats](https://serde.rs/#data-formats) if you're interested.